# Convert work area to the line of type internal table

Tags: abap, opensql

I am getting this syntax error:

> "WA_1" cannot be converted to the line type of "IT_1"

I'm trying to display contents from internal table as follows:

```
REPORT  ZSAM.

DATA: ITable Type ZMUAZ_STRUCTURE OCCURS 10,
      IT_1 Type ZSTRUCT1 OCCURS 10,
      IT_2 Type ZSTRUCT2 OCCURS 10,
      WA_1 like IT_1,
      WA_2 like IT_2,
      WA_3 like ITable.

WRITE: 'vbeln', 'vtweg', 'posnr', 'matnrr','vrkme'.

select vbeln audat netwr waerk vkorg vtweg from VBAK into corresponding fields of Table IT_1.

LOOP AT IT_1 INTO WA_1.

write: /  WA_1-vbeln, WA_1-audat, WA_1-netwr, WA_1-waerk, WA_1-vkorg, WA_1-vtweg.

endloop.
```

Any idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: Hi mj111261829, are you learning from some kind of an old book? There have been some serious changes introduced to the language over the years. You should definitely get some newer one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wa_1` is declared as internal table (not as work area). The simplest solution is to complete the declaration with [`LINE OF`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abentyping_complete.htm):

```
... wa_1 LIKE LINE OF it_1,
```

However declaring internal tables and work areas like you did with [`OCCURS` is obsolete](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapdata_occurs.htm), its modern equivalent is [`STANDARD TABLE OF`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapdata_itab.htm) :

```
DATA: it_1 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF zstruct1,
      wa_1 TYPE zstruct1.
```